# (Re)Setting defaults preference on OSX for one folder excluding subfolders

Tags: macos, terminal, metadata, finder, preference

I am trying to understand the "overall" file metadata vs preference default settings -logic with osx mav on my mac. After all I am totally confused

**The issue:**

I set up my default com.apple.. to show hidden files in finder ✓

Now I want to change this default preference for one folder to


▸ hide items set to be invisible only within this specific folder

▸ I don't want to inherit this on sub folders

Where and how can this be done?

In specific I want this to happen in my users-folder
mac: /Users/Me/**Set this here**/*but not here/not there/.../...*

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: ...yes, thanks - good idea -done and reposted [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/140662/86541)